# Extracting per-participant estimated sigma squared for longitudinal dataset using by, dlply, and lapply

Tags: r, plyr, lapply

I am working through my own longitudinal dataset following Chapter 3 of 'Applied Longitudinal Data Analysis' by Singer and Willett.

I am trying to obtain estimated residual variance for each participant in my study using the R code listed [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/examples/alda/ch3.htm)

Toy data follows: Score on a questionnaire for 4 participants each measured 5 times at different doses of a drug.

```
Dose <- rep(c("Dose40mg", "Dose30mg", "Dose20mg", "Dose10mg", "Dose0mg"), 4)
ID <- rep(1:4, each = 5)
set.seed(123)
Score <- rnorm(20, 10, 3)
df <- data.frame(ID, Dose, Score)
```

To get the sigma squared (residual variance) for each participant the code in the book would translate to this dataset as:

```
sig <- by(df, df$ID, function(data) (summary(lm(Score ~ Dose, data=data))$sigma)^2 )
```

However this does not work

I looked around on stackoverflow for my own workaround can came up with

```
f <- dlply(df, .(ID), lm, formula = Score ~ Dose)

s <- lapply(f, summary)

sig <- lapply(s, function (x) (x$sigma)^2)
```

Which is unwieldy, and even worse, also doesn't work.

The eventual goal is to get the residual variance for each participant into a stem and leaf plot. But I need the values first. What am I missing?

Comment: By does not work, you mean that you get NA? This is perfectly ok, because for each ID your model is a perfect fit. Your independent variable is categorical and has the same number of values as the entire dataset.

Comment: Yes I get NaN for each sigma squared. Shouldn't the fitted intercept and slope for each participant yield estimates at each wave of data that is slightly different from the actual value (thus yielding a residual), or am I misunderstanding something fundamental (very likely)? Also the example from the book chapter yields non-NaN sigma-squared for each participant, so I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Which code in the link corresponds exactly to your data set? I suspect that your question is not related with R code, but with model fitting. Your model would be fine if you wanted to get a relationship between the score and the the numerical value of a dose, i.e. 10 + 3 * 10 mg = 40 score. Now you treat each dose as a separate value.

Comment: In code terms `Dose <- rep(c(40,30,20,10,0), 4)` would produce non-NA sigma values.

Comment: Ah yes. Makes sense. I wasn't really thinking about what the lm was doing but it needs a correlation between two things and I guess a categorical variable doesn't really do that. Thank you.